# Pytorch semantic segmentation loss function

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I’m new to segmentation model.
I would like to use the **deeplabv3_resnet50** model.
My image has shape `(256, 256, 3)` and my label has shape `(256, 256)`. Each pixel in my label has a class value(0-4). And the batch size set in the DataLoader is 32.
Therefore, the shape of my input batch is `[32, 3, 256, 256]` and the shape of corresponding target is `[32, 256, 256]`. I believe this is correct.

I was trying to use `nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()`.

1. Is this the correct loss function for my case? Or should I use
   `CrossEntropy` instead?
2. If this is the right one, the output of my model is `[32, 5, 256, 256]`. Each image prediction has the shape `[5,256, 256]`, does layer 0 means the unnomarlized probabilities of class 0? In order to make a `[32, 256, 256]` tensor to match the target to feed into the `BCEWithLogitsLoss`, do I need to transform the unnomarlized probabilities to classes?
3. If I should use `CrossEntropy`, what the size of my output and label should be?

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the wrong loss function.

[`nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss) stands for *Binary* Cross-Entropy loss: that is a loss for *Binary* labels. In your case, you have 5 labels (0..4).
You should be using [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss): a loss designed for discrete labels, beyond the binary case.

Your models should output a tensor of shape `[32, 5, 256, 256]`: for each pixel in the 32 images of the batch, it should output a 5-dim vector of *logits*. The *logits* are the "raw" scores for each class, to be later on normalize to class probabilities using softmax function.
For numerical stability and computational efficiency, [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) does not require you to explicitly compute the softmax of the logits, but does it internally for you. As the documentation read:

> This criterion combines LogSoftmax and NLLLoss in one single class.

Comment: got it. If I would like to calculate IOU or pixel accuracy later, should I make the output to be `[32, 256, 256]` (maybe output.argmax(dim=1)) to match my label?

Comment: @KKKcat argmax over the channel dim should give you the predicted labels

Answer (score 1):

Given you are dealing with 5 classes, you should use CrossEntropyLoss. Binary cross-entropy, as the name suggests is a loss function you use when you have a binary segmentation map.

The CrossEntropy function, in PyTorch, expects the output from your model to be of the shape - `[batch, num_classes, H, W]`(pass this directly to your loss function) and the ground truth to be of shape `[batch, H, W]` where `H, W` in your case is 256, 256. Also please make sure the ground truth is of type `long` by calling `.long()` on the tensor